# Fetch data from sql query array don't work in Laravel 5.2 Controller

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

This is a Controller from a Laravel 5.2 Project. I'm new in Laravel.
I want to use the values in the array by index.
The error I'm getting is:

```
Undefined Offset: 1   LINE: if($rows[1]==0)
```

How i can fix this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class testeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $cont=0;
        $cont_aux=0;

        $sql = "SELECT a.id_citacao, a.prazo_manual, a.recetor, b.urgente, c.prazo_normal, c.prazo_urgente, d.contador_notificado, d.prazo_citacao, b.id_residencia, f.comarca, f.prazo_dilatorio, f.localidade, f.comarca, f.ilha, e.id_residencia, f1.localidade, f1.comarca,f1.prazo_dilatorio, f1.ilha,d.id_tipo_rececao FROM citacao a, processo b, tipo_processo c, tipo_rececao d, constituinte e, residencia f, residencia f1 WHERE a.id_processo = b.id_processo AND b.id_tipo_processo = c.id_tipo_processo AND a.id_tipo_rececao = d.id_tipo_rececao AND e.id_constituinte = b.id_constituinte AND f.id_residencia = e.id_residencia AND f1.id_residencia = b.id_residencia ORDER BY a.id_citacao DESC LIMIT 1 ";

        $rows = \DB::select($sql);

        if($rows[1]==0){
            if ($rows[3]=='true'){
                $cont=$rows[5];
                $cont_aux=$cont;
            }
            else {
                $cont=$rows[4];
                $cont_aux=$cont;
            }
        }

        return view('listar_info',compact('cont','cont_aux'));

        view('constituintes.formwizard',compact('residencias','attributes'));
    }
}
```

Before I started using Laravel I used this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: After `$rows = \DB::select($sql);` put this line `dd($rows)`. See what index you are getting.

Comment: What does `var_dump($rows);` print?

Comment: shouldnt this be like this `$rows = \DB::select(DB::raw ($sql);`  also we need to see the out put so please `dd($rows);` it will help to identify the probleme.

Comment: Instead of `\DB` it should be `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` and rather than using raw queries why don't you use Eloquent way

Comment: DB::select($sql) will return the rows in the result. Therefore, your code here doesn't really make any sense. Also, checking `if($rows[1]==0)` will give an undefined offset error if there's either only one or no results for your query which is most probably the source of the error here.